# Rails query deeper belongs_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I'm running Rails 4 and have a number of models who are related.

```
User
  has_many :picks

Game
  has_many :picks
  belongs_to :week

Pick
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :game

Week
  has_many :games
```

Given a user, I would like to get all of his picks for a given week, determined by an attribute of week (i.e. number).

The query should be something like the following:

`user.picks.where(game.week.number = 1) # => all of user's picks for week one`

If it changes anything, I am using Postgres 9.4

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use multiple joins :

```
user.picks.joins(games: :week).where(games: { week: { number: 1 } })
```

Comment: Updated my answer, you can join nested associations.